# Vuetify Combobox not updating to correct value

Tags: vue.js, combobox, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify combobox that on save does an api call to store the selected or entered value. However, when updating this value, if the save button is clicked directly without deselecting the combobox, the previously stored value is stored again, instead of the new value. Only when I manually unselect the box or press enter does the correct value store. I have looked around and found certain fixes that have worked for others, such as .blur() and .$nextTick, but they haven't seemed to work for me (I could be implementing them incorrectly). Here's what I have:

Combobox:

```
<v-combobox
  :items="suggestions"
  v-model="editedItem.field_label"
  label="Label"
  outlined
  dense
  ref = "comboBox"
></v-combobox>
```

Save button:

```
<v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="save"> Save</v-btn>
```

Save function:

```
save() {
  this.$refs.comboBox.$emit("blur")
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    const device_field = {
      ...this.editedItem,
    };
      device_field_api
        .updateDeviceField(device_field, this.device_id)
        .then((r) => {
          //Various logging items
          );
        })
        .finally(this.initialize())
        .catch((e) => {
          //Error catching
          );
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Would you provide a fiddle or more information around data property?

Comment: It's working fine. `device_field` is always updated when you try to log it. Maybe it has something to do with how you fetch and/or how you store, or completely something else. You can create a [fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/) so we can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change
`this.$refs.comboBox.$emit("blur")`
to this:
`this.$refs.comboBox.blur()`.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/lazac92/pen/eYZjzEy?editors=1011)

Result:
[image]

Comment: Tried that before, doesn't change the result.

Comment: Here, a working example:
https://codepen.io/lazac92/pen/eYZjzEy?editors=1011

Comment: This example works both with how I have it, as well as with the change. The error must be elsewhere in my code.